# Java servlet request javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException - Premature end of file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jetty, httprequest

I am trying to read and parse an rss feed from a 2 jetty servers (Eclipse - Google Plugin): one with App engine SDK enabled and one without it. 
1. When i test on the jetty run with app engine enabled it works fine
2. When i use the same code on a jetty server without app engine enabled i get the following message (because the received text is empty):

javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.

I searched the code for a premature reading of the input stream (I use new URL(host) and url.openStream() to read the input), but the code is OK (if it wasn't it wouldn't probably work in the first case).

I used tcpdump (-s 1024 -l -A dst host.com -i wlan0) to examine the headers:

1. first case:

   GET /rss/... HTTP/1.1

   Host: www.host.com

   Connection: Keep-Alive

   Cookie: environment=a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A4%3A%22skin%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22default%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22lang%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22ro_RO%22%3B%7D; isPC=1

   Cookie2: $Version=1
2. second case:

   GET /rss/... HTTP/1.1

   Cache-Control: no-cache

   Pragma: no-cache

   User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_39

   Host: www.host.com

   Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2

   Connection: keep-alive

Could those headers be the issue ? Is there a way to set the exact same headers ? And would it solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seams that the problem was the User-Agent header, which determined some servers to send empty content for some values (like Jav/1.6.0_39 in my case). I set the User-Agent to empty string and now the response is ok.